# hold data in session while user leaves page and returns

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am working on an car hire site and I am storing the users details in session(additional drivers details). Once the user is ready to make payment, they are redirected to a payment gateway and once payment is made the user is redirected back to the site. At this stage an invoice is being drawn up and requires the details stored in session.

As I have it at the moment, My invoice shows blank(no details on it). Is it because the session may have ended once user was redirected off my site and onto the payment gateway?, If this is what happened, Is it possible to edit the sessionState in the web.config file to hold the values while redirecting occurs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to play it safe,

- Create an order in your database with PENDING status
- When you are redirected to the payment website, send your **OrderID** as an additional parameter (I never saw any payment systems that don't accept additional custom parameters, so I assume yours should support this function too)
- When the payment system redirects the user back to your website, it should send the **OrderID** back to you.
- Now you don't need to use Session, which might expire, any more

Comment: Thank you Michael, I guess I am going to use this way of reconciling the report, this is the fool proof way to go.